# Rails 3 pass params to Iframe fancybox

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, fancybox, parameters

I'm trying to achieve something with Rails and Fancybox but seems hard to do...

In my application, I have a link_to function like:

```
<% @factures.each do |facture| %>
<tr>
<td><%= facture.numero %></td>
<td><%= facture.date %></td>
<td><%= facture.contact %></td>
<td><%= facture.journal_id %></td>
<td class="fancybox"><%= link_to 'Ajouter un paiement', new_facture_paiement_path(:facture_id => facture.id) %></td>
```

Then I have a Jquery code that open a modal iframe fancybox when the user click on the link:

```
$(function () {
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
'type' : 'iframe',
'href' : '/facture_paiements/new'
});
});
```

Modal fancybox opens like a charm but I cannot find a way to get the param :facture_id to prepopulate the corresponding field in my modal box...

Is it possible to pass the param to the iframe fancybox via the javascript?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, why don't you use `ajax` type of Fancybox?

```
$(function () {
  $('.fancybox a').fancybox({'type' : 'ajax'});
});
```

Anyways there's no need to pass `href` parameter to the `fancybox`, as long as you "fancyboxifying" link (which already has this attribute). Notice, that you either have to add a `fancybox` class to a link directly:

```
<td<%= link_to 'Ajouter un paiement', new_facture_paiement_path(:facture_id => facture.id), :class => 'fancybox' %></td>
```

either use jQuery selector as provided above.